# @Media Query- min-width not working but max-width yes

Tags: media-queries

The min-width not working but the max-width yes.

This is the meta tag:
 `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

This is my code:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1301px) {
        .video-banner {
            width: 100%;
            height: 575px;
            margin: 0;
            background: white;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
     .video-banner {
            width: 100%;
            height: 250px;
            margin: 0;
            background: white;
            border: 1px solid white;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe that your first media query `min-width: 1301px` would target screens with a _minimum_ width of 1301 pixels.  Is this what you intended?

Comment: Thanks Tim,  i also tried different values and only the max works.

Comment: You should tell us for which devices and sizes don't "work."